# How to use a non-wordpress index.php in a wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a wordpress website, I would like to use a custom non-wordpress index.php on it.
Unfortunately we all know the pages of wordpress are loaded using the initial index.php as first loader.
How could I do it?

If I change the index.php file then there is no way to reach the other pages in wordpress.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? If you need to add code you can use wp-config.php. Bit I think you can just rename the existing index.php tot something else, add you custom index.php. And include the renamed file in it.

Comment: I can’t think of a practical application though. So please share why you would want to do this.

Comment: The problem is, I have this wordpress website, I need to keep some pages and functionalities, but I would like to fully customize the homepage and others. The website is well indexed on Google and all the pages are developed using Elementor so I cannot customized it without making mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Best option is to leave the wordpress installation as is. So not change the index.php.

If you need some of the pages to use a different php or html file, you should use rewriterules to redirect those url’s to these different pages. In the .htaccess file in the root, you will find some rules added by wordpress. Before these lines you can add your own rules to “intercept” some of the urls to different php files. For example, the home url: you can create a new file called home.php and rewrite the request to this file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /home.php [L]
```

Where ^ means start of the path and $ the end of the path. So no path in this case, which means the home page. If you need another path, for example `products` to point to a custom file, for example `products.php`, you would write `^products$ /products.php`.